# Populate an array of objects using hashmap

Tags: java, arrays, for-loop, hashmap, populate

I am new to hashmaps and even though I was trying to read about it, I couldn't really solve my issue.

This is the part of my code where I have this issue.

```
public HeatmapData(HashMap<Node, ArrayList<ODData>> ODs)
{
    /* get all of the origins */
    Node [] row = ODs.keySet().toArray(new Node[0]);
    Node [] column = new Node[row.length];
    System.arraycopy(row, 0, column, 0, row.length);

    ODData [] routes = new ODData[ROUTES_SIZE];     

    for (int i=0; i<ROUTES_SIZE; i++)
    {
        ODData temp = new ODData();
        // Node n = row[i];

        routes[i] = temp;

        //routes = (ODData[]) ODs.get(n).toArray(new ODData[0]);            
    }
```

As you can see I can't really find a way that will copy the data from the original hashmap to my array of objects.

I basically need to find the first node in array "row", find its values from the hashmpap, populate my array "routes[]", and then do the same with the second node in array "row". It seems like every time I try I have miss match error or a null value.

The program reads from two files that look as follows:

First:

```
100001 200002 6
100001 200003 9
...............
```

Second:

```
100001 -97.5489 30.5846
100002 -97.6958 30.5986
...............
```

My node class consists of

```
int ID;
double longititude;
double lattitude;
```

And my ODData class consists of

```
Node origin;
Node destination;
double value;
```

Each 10000 number has many 20000 numbers relating to it.

Using the hashmap that is being send to the function, I need to populate my ODData routes[] array with these ODData objects so it will look like the original file (the first one).

Any idea how it can be done?
I'll appreciate any help!

Nikita

Comment: why do you have this ? new Node[0]

Comment: This part actually works fine. It populates arrays "row" and "colom" with the right nodes. My problem is in the loop.

Comment: What exactly is  the problem ?

Comment: it does not point to any where? what is the error or issue that you have with the  loop?

Comment: I can't find the right logic in populating my routes[] with the right data from the hashmap. I have both "row" and "colom" arrays right, but I just can't find a way to use the nodes in those arrays to find the corresponding values in the hashmap.
I feel like there should be a build-in method that lets me find the value while entering the key, but I can't fine one.

Comment: The "Node n" should be the key and the "ArrayList<ODData>>" should be the value, but it doesn't let me do it. It's either a miss match or a null value.

Comment: Please post complete code and what actually do you want to do?

Comment: I couldn't write it here so I added my original post. @AnkitSharma

Comment: Means you wanna populate your HashMap Where Key is class Node object and Value is array list of class ODData ?

Comment: I want to populate my routes[] array with ODData objects where Key class is Node object and Value is array list of class ODData. @AnkitSharma

Comment: I am not sure what are trying to achieve.? But my guess is your map contains the arraylist of object of ODDdata as value and you need the value in your map to be stored in an array called routes[]. Am i correct?

Comment: you wanna populate a Map to an Array or ArrayList?. You can get the Keys in one array and Values in different array and there is no guarantee of their order. You can't get both Keys and Values in single array.

Comment: Yes, you are 100% correct. @Jayaprasad.

Comment: I need to use the "row[i]" array as the Key and then populate the routes[] array with the corresponding ODData Values. @AnkitSharma

Comment: why do you want to do this? How are you going to use this?

Comment: These Nodes are coordinates and the ODData are routes that car travel. With this data I am creating a heatmap and use different kinds of clustering. @AnkitSharma

Comment: So where is the problem? The same you can do by Map too. Why Array?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to iterate the hash map and get the value of map and convert the arraylist (value of your hash map) to the array using toArray() of arraylist. But in your design the routes array has limited size, which will have memory wastage.

public class FetchMapData {

```
static final int ROUTES_SIZE = 10;

public void HeatMap(HashMap<String, ArrayList<ODData>> map) {

    int totalLength = 0;

    ArrayList<ODData> alist = new ArrayList<ODData>();

    ODData[] routes = new ODData[ROUTES_SIZE];
    ODData[] tmpRoutes = new ODData[ROUTES_SIZE];

    for (String key : map.keySet()) {
        alist = map.get(key);
        // this will have an impact as your array size limited to
        // ROUTES_SIZE
        tmpRoutes = alist.toArray(new ODData[alist.size()]);
        System.arraycopy(tmpRoutes, 0, routes, totalLength,
                tmpRoutes.length);
        totalLength = totalLength + tmpRoutes.length;
    }
    for (int i = 0, length = routes.length; i < length; i++) {
        if (routes[i] != null) {
            System.out.println(routes[i].getOrigin() + "        "
                    + routes[i].getDestination() + "        "
                    + routes[i].getValue());
        }
    }
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    HashMap<String, ArrayList<ODData>> heatMap = new HashMap<String, ArrayList<ODData>>();

    ArrayList<ODData> list1 = new ArrayList<ODData>();
    ArrayList<ODData> list2 = new ArrayList<ODData>();
    ODData obj1 = new ODData("s1", "s2", 1.1);
    ODData obj2 = new ODData("s3", "s4", 2.1);
    ODData obj3 = new ODData("s5", "s6", 3.1);
    ODData obj4 = new ODData("s7", "s8", 4.1);
    list1.add(obj1);
    list1.add(obj2);
    list2.add(obj3);
    list2.add(obj4);
    heatMap.put("key1", list1);
    heatMap.put("key2", list2);

    FetchMapData fetchMapDataObj = new FetchMapData();
    fetchMapDataObj.HeatMap(heatMap);
}
```

}

**Output:**

```
s5      s6      3.1
s7      s8      4.1
s1      s2      1.1
s3      s4      2.1
```

You modify the String in hashmap to Node as per your requirement. if you want to maintain the sorting order then use TreeMap instead of HashMap.

Comment: This code works perfect! The only issue is that every time the key changes, the routes[] is being assigned from the beginning and not from the pint where it stopped. For an example:

100001 200002 8

100001 200003 9

100001 200004 5

...............

And then when the key changes to 100002, all the data above is being erased.

Comment: I wish I could rate your solution because it works exactly the way I wanted it to! I don't have enough reputation apparently. I just ran the code and it outputted all the values but for some reason it still doesn't create the heatmap. When I use debug, it shows that that routes[] is being populated with the addresses (ctr.ODData@52c03865 and etc.) instead with the values. Am I missing something?